# What do you call a name which has an adjective / describing word like "the Great" as part of it?

Tags: single-word-requests, names, nicknames

E.g. Charles the Great, Charles the Rash, Edward the Confessor, etc.

I'm reasonably sure there was a word for this .... * *scratches head* *

Comment: Charles the Rash probably had to scratch a lot also.

Comment: I'm not sure why this rather than the earlier 'duplicate' has been closed, @Laurel. Yes, the title question reads better, but is it more readily searchable? Charles the Great, Charles the Rash, Edward the Confessor ... Peter the Great is perhaps an unlikely search element. Perhaps an edit to the title here?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The other question has more answers is all. Anyone who comes here can click on the link in the header to see the other question so it doesn't really matter which one is more searchable.

Comment: @Laurel I suppose that the 'credit where credit's due' consideration (closure is often a pejorative sign) loses force over time. I'd still prefer an edited melding of duplicate threads,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was (and still **is**! :) an [**epithet**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/epithet)...

> any word or phrase applied to a person or thing to describe an actual or attributed quality
>   “Richard the Lion-Hearted” is an epithet of Richard I.